# How to suppress null pointer access warning in java?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, annotations, suppress-warnings

I am using eclipse IDE.

I have a code which throws `NullPointerException` and I am handling the exception using `try/catch` `block`

This is my code -

```
        String name = null;
        int length = 0;

        try {
            length = name.length();
            System.out.println("Number of letters in name: " + length);
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("NullPointerException occured");
        }

        System.out.println("I am being executed");
```

within the `try` `block` on the line having `identifier` `length` I am having the warning -

`Null pointer access: The variable name can only be null at this location`

I am trying to suppress the warning by using -

```
            @SuppressWarnings("all")
            length = name.length();
```

Here on the line having `identifier` `length` I am having the error -

```
Multiple markers at this line -
- Syntax error on token "length", VariableDecalaratorId expected after this token
- Null pointer access: The variable name can only be null at this location
- length cannot be resolved to a type
```

How to resolve this problem?

I don't want my program to show this warning as I am aware of what I am doing.

Comment: Making it so the variable has a chance of being non-null would be a good resolution. Right now, `name` is _guaranteed_ to be `null`.

Comment: What you have is legal Java. A warning doesn't stop the code running, it's just warning you of a potential problem, just in case you didn't really intend to do what you did.

Comment: @user85421 thanks I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by @Slaw for this answer -

I modified my code in the following way -

```
        String name = null;
        int length = 0;

        boolean flag = false;
        if(flag) {
            name = "abcd";
        }

        try {

            length = name.length();
            System.out.println("Number of letters in name: " + length);
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("NullPointerException occured");
        }

        System.out.println("I am being executed");
```

Now I longer have the warning.

Here, as suggested by @Slaw I made sure that the `variable` `name` has a chance of not being `null`.

Comment: Well, it certainly removes the warning, but it's not quite what I meant. I meant write the code so it doesn't throw an NPE, whether the IDE/compiler can warn about it or not. Why are you trying to force an NPE?

Comment: I am actually new to java and learning various types of exceptions and how to handle them.

Comment: In that case, I personally would (probably) never catch a `NullPointerException`. Such an exception means there's a flaw in the logic of the program and it would be best to let (part of) the application crash then go and fix the problem so the NPE isn't thrown again.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following annotation to either the method or class to suppress warnings about potential `NullPointerException`s being thrown. This works in Intellij, although I am unsure about Eclipse.

```
@SuppressWarnings("DataFlowIssue")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).